If the Septuagint wasn't a single publication why do we treat it like one?
It is to my understanding that before Origen made his recension of the Septuagint we didn't actually have any of its books in a compiled volume and that synagogues and the early church prior to this, and the the invention of the codex, simply collected individual scrolls of the books of the Bible to study and preach from.
If this is the case why do people make sweeping statements like "The apostles quoted from the Septuagint", "The majority of NT quotes of the OT align more closely with the Septuagint than the MT", and "The Jews moved away from use of the Septuagint because of it's association with Christians?"
Were the scrolls usually copied and transported as a collection or something? What reasons do we have to treat the Septuagint other than the Pentateuch as one entity, especially in regarding to the first century believers and what they regarded as scripture?
This isn't meant to be an attack on the Septuagint, I genuinely want to know, and surfing the web doesn't seem to be much help in this case.
Edit: Thanks for your responses guys. Just for clarification the examples I gave aren't actually any personal objections I have. The actual thing I'm trying to sort out in my own head is whether this line of thinking has any merit. "The apostles quoted the Septuagint, and the Septuagint includes Deuterocanon, therefore Deuterocanon is inspired." But I can't actually find any reason to think that the Deuterocanon was truly considered a part of the collection as much as it was just other religious writings that were in use at the time until later canon debates. Perhaps in the minds of certain people at the time no distinction was made between the scrolls in use, but Josephus' canon, who was around at the same time as the apostles, seems to reflect a canon many people still use today.
Again this isn't meant to be a "gotcha" for people who believe Deuterocanon to be inspired. I've just been researching and questioning my own canon as a protestant and the NT quotes of "The Septuagint" had me reevaluating my relationship with Deuterocanon and books like Enoch. Naturally the answer to this question will have a large impact on my stance.

It is true that the LXX is an umbrella term the same as Tanakh is and NT is.  The fact remains that under this umbrella, your assertions in italics are generally true.

There were Jewish Recension's before Origen. There is good information on this topic here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4347/recensions-of-the-septuagint

and welcome to the group! For future reference please to to include specific biblical passages for us to work with. This question isn't off topic IMO but please read the Tour and the FAQ pages for orientation if you have not done so.

It's very common to refer to collective works by a collective name.  For example, "I consulted the Encyclopedia Britannica" or "I saw it in Sports Illustrated".  That does not depend on or imply that the collective work is packaged as a single physical unit.

Our treatment of the LXX as a single document is little different from our treatment of the "Old Testament" itself as a single document. When Jesus lived, there was, in fact, no such thing as the OT. The Jewish scriptures were simply various collections of scrolls and there was no consensus as to which books other than the Torah were authoritative. The NT itself even seems to treat the Book of Enoch as scripture (Jude 1:14) even though it appears in neither the LXX nor the MT.
People say "The apostles quoted from the Septuagint" because these quotes are clearly from the Greek version of what we call the OT rather than the Hebrew versions. The same may be said of the statement: "The majority of NT quotes of the OT align more closely with the Septuagint than the MT."
The statement "The Jews moved away from use of the Septuagint because of its association with Christians" is no more true that the statement "Christians used the Greek OT rather than the Hebrew version because of its association with Jews."  There simply was no canonical OT as such when the apostles and early Church Fathers wrote. The fact is that the LXX could be read by Christians, because Christians could read Greek more easily than Hebrew, whether these Greek scriptures were read as individual books or as a collection.
Conclusion: we treat the LXX as a single entity for the same reason that we treat the OT itself as a single book.

It took me only two minutes to come up with this website, which openly stated that the Septuagint came from the Latin for 'seventy', explaining that:

"...seventy-two Judean scholars (six from each of the twelve tribes of
Israel) who, according to legend, came together around 250 B.C. in
Alexandria, Egypt (then one of the world's greatest centers of
learning) to translate the Pentateuch - that is, the Torah, or Five
Books of Moses - from its original Hebrew into Greek. (Ptolemy, the
Greek ruler of Egypt, requested this translation because by the time
of his reign so few Jews throughout the vast Greek empire spoke
Hebrew...
The resultant volume - which ultimately took at least one hundred
years to finish, and included the entire Old Testament - is known as
the Septuagint... These scholars labored to translate God's language into man's on the island of Pharos, just off the coast of Alexandria, Egypt, in a learning complex that also contained the Lighthouse of Alexandria, one of the Seven Wonders of the ancient world."   https://www.crosswalk.com/faith/bible-study/what-is-the-septuagint-11632725.html

That is not a unique site. This Hermeneutics site looks for research evidence from the OP, so if you could state your sources, that would be helpful.
It baffles me how anybody could think of the Septuagint as "a single volume" until the forerunner of books - the Codex - had been invented. This early version of the book we’re all familiar with today brought pages together by binding them at one edge. This new setup was easier to flip through, and was sturdier than manuscripts rolled up into a scroll. Manuscript scrolls would be pulled out when a particular portion was to be read from. The person requesting that would have to know which part of the Old Testament they needed. When Jesus went to the synagogue one Sabbath day, he was given the scroll of Isaiah to read from, publicly. He unrolled it till he found the bit that prophetically applied to himself, read it out aloud and said that bit had now been fulfilled in their hearing. Read Luke 4:15-21.
Of note also is that the original Septuagint scrolls were all written, and kept together, where the world-famous library at Alexandria was. Although it took 100 years to complete translating all of the Hebrew scriptures, they could then be viewed as being one "volume" when housed together in that library. But, of course, they remained as a collection of many individual scrolls. However, there is nothing misleading about speaking of the finished Septuagint as one, completed work, or 'volume'. Then, when the Codex was invented, the Septuagint could only come together as one complete collection then. Some people today might not realise that, of course.
The problem lies with modern-day people who think their way of thinking is what they need to base assertions and questions upon. Anyone prepared to look at the matter from the way things actually were back in the day would never think the Septuagint was one giant scroll! Just knowing about the Isaiah scroll Jesus read from (as in Luke 4:15-21) shows how things were back then. Also consider Paul, who requested that "the scrolls, especially the parchments" be brought to him (2 Timothy 4:13).
Someone else may wish to enlarge on the three claims you object to, but having dealt with the basis of the objection, I will end my answer here, which simply is, "The Septuagint never was a single volume until the Codex had been invented." The oldest extant Greek codex, said to date from the 4th century, is the Codex Sinaiticus, a biblical manuscript written in Greek. Around then, the Septuagint could have been bound as a Codex, but not until. https://www.britannica.com/topic/codex-manuscript

"The problem lies with modern-day people who think their way of thinking is what they need to base assertions and questions upon" it is not wrong to ask for a clarification of one's own understanding.

@DavidD  Of course not, which is why I answered. But I do apologize if I gave the misleading impression that I was in any way looking down on the OPs question.

@Anne Those three quotes I gave were just examples and not any personal objection of mine. Edited my original post to clarify. Thanks for your response and sorry for any confusion.
